# Match anything but this group of characters?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I'm looking for a pattern that will match anything but this:

```
"/[a-z0-9]/i"
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `^`, which negates a character set.

You want `/[^a-z0-9]/i`.

`[a-z]` matches a..z. `[^a-z]` matches anything **not** a..z.

Comment: But isn't that different from matching anything but that match? For example, both of your regex match `"A$"`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy see my answer, it explains it there.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Can you provide an example of how "not matching" and "matching anything but" is somehow different than what I've posted?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: OP asked specifically about "anything but a group of characters", so this satisfies the question perfectly. `/[a-z][a-z]/` cannot be simply negated into `/[^a-z][^a-z]/`, but that was not what was asked.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy [post-edit]: No, both of them will find a match in `"A$"`; but the match will be `"A"` for the OP's regexp, and `"$"` for the one in the answer. The character group that is matched is different.

Answer (score 1):

`/[^a-z0-9]/i`

The `^` at the start inside a `[ ]` means "none of these" rather than the conventional "any of these"

If he wants something matches not a-z0-9 one time, this is it. this matches spaces, everything that isn't a-z0-9, one time